# How to get RecyclerView onClick working in a Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

After many days getting Fragment to actually display I now find myself struggling to be able to allow clicking items in recyclerview. I have read numerous postings on how to do it but I must be missing something. 
First let me say my Background has been years as a VB developer.

Here is what I currently have in my Fragment Java.

```
    package com.procatdt.stockright.activities;
    import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import com.procatdt.stockright.R;
    import com.procatdt.stockright.models.ItemsListModel;
    import com.procatdt.stockright.utils.DatabaseMgr;
    import java.util.List;

    public class SelectItemFragment extends  Fragment {
    private RecyclerAdapter mRecyclerAdapter;
    private String mParam1;
    private Bundle args;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private List <ItemsListModel> myItems;
    private ItemsListModel mItem;
    private Button btnSelect;


    public SelectItemFragment newInstance(String param1) {
        SelectItemFragment fragment = new SelectItemFragment();
        args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("valuesArray", param1);
        String mParam1 = param1;
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        mParam1 = bundle.toString();
        String name = this.getArguments().getString("valuesArray").toString();

        String newParam1 = name;
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_select_item, container, false);
        btnSelect = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnSelectItem);
        myItems = DatabaseMgr.getItemsList(newParam1);

        if (myItems.size() > 0) {
            myItems.get(0).setSelected(true);
            mItem = new ItemsListModel(myItems.get(0));
        }
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.lRecyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        mRecyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(myItems);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mRecyclerAdapter);

        return (view);
    }
    private class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerHolder> {
        private RecyclerViewClickListener mListener;
        private List <ItemsListModel> items;


        RecyclerAdapter(RecyclerViewClickListener listener){
            mListener=listener;
        }

        public RecyclerAdapter(List <ItemsListModel> itemList) {

          items = itemList;
        }

        @Override
        public   RecyclerHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_select_item, parent, false);
            return new RecyclerHolder(view);
        }
        public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerHolder recyclerholder, int position) {
            ItemsListModel item = items.get(position);
            if (item.isSelected()) {
                recyclerholder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorYellow));
            } else {
                recyclerholder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorWhite));
            }
            recyclerholder.bindRecyclerData(item);
        }
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return items.size();
        }
    }

    public class RecyclerHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        private TextView mlItem;
        private TextView mLVL;
        private TextView mLVLd;
        private TextView mDesc;
        private ItemsListModel mItems;


        public RecyclerHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mlItem = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_item);
            mLVL = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_LVL);
            mLVLd = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_LVLd);
            mDesc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_desc);
        }

        public void bindRecyclerData(ItemsListModel newItem) {
            mItems = newItem;
            mlItem.setText(mItems.getiItem());
            mLVL.setText(mItems.getiLVL());
            mLVLd.setText(mItems.getiLVLd());
            mDesc.setText(mItems.getiDesc());
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            for (int i = 0; i < myItems.size(); i++) {
                if (myItems.get(i).equals(mItem)) {
                    myItems.get(i).setSelected(true);
                    mItem = new ItemsListModel(myItems.get(i));
                } else {
                    myItems.get(i).setSelected(false);
                }
            }
            mRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        public void onbtnClick(View view){

        }

    }

    public interface RecyclerViewClickListener {
        void onClick(View view, int position);
    }
}
```

The XML for the fragment is.

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.procatdt.stockright.activities.SelectItemFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <!--      <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/newFrame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true">-->


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_item"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:gravity="start|right"
            android:text="Item" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_LVL"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text_view_item"
            android:text="LVL" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_LVLd"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text_view_LVL"
            android:text="LvlDesc" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_desc"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text_view_LVLd"
            android:text="Description" />


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/lRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="115dp"

            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSelectItem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="220dp"
            android:onClick="onbtnClick"
            android:text="Select Item" />

        <!--</FrameLayout>-->
    </RelativeLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/colorBackgroundGray"
        android:layout_below="@id/layout"
        style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

When the I click on any of the items in recyclerview nothing happens. I would like the item I click to be highlighted and let me know what row in recyclerview has been selected. I have been not having issues with recyclerviews in activities but fragments only.

Any pointers would be most appreciated.
Tom

Answer (score 2):

I think you forget `itemView.setOnClickListener(this);`

Try this:

```
public RecyclerHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mlItem = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_item);
            mLVL = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_LVL);
            mLVLd = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_LVLd);
            mDesc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_desc);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I see the listener firing. However when it hits code to change the selected row to be highlighted in yellow during onBindViewHolder position is coming back as 0 and none of the items are highlighted in Yellow. Any clue on what I am missing

Comment: Hello Tom, I do not understand well what you want to achieve, can you explain me better please?

Comment: Gabriel, what I am attempting is activity calls fragment when they scan something that comes back with more than 1 match, the fragment gets called displaying the matching items in a recyclerview. The user then can select the item they want and that item will get returned to activity. I get the items to display in fragment. when fragment first displays first row is highlited yellow. If I select 2 row I would like to have that row turn yellow. User then knows what item is selected and clicks button on screen to return to calling activity bringind item number back to activity.

Comment: Reason I am using fragment is that this scenario can happen from different activities and I'd rather resuse the fragment

Comment: Hello Tom, first of all I tell you that I do not understand English at 100%. I commented on what I understood.
I think you try to perform an action when you select several items from your list, if so, I suggest you use the ActionMode component. Normally it shows you a menu in the toolbar to perform actions on the selected elements. On the internet there are many tutorials on this.

Comment: Gabriel. I got it. Thanks for the help. You solved my issue